# is incrementing a function argument a good way to update a "counter" using recursion?

Tags: java, recursion, counter

I am practising with recursion and have been looking at the question:

"*Write a recursive program whose input is an array A and a number x. The program should print the number of occurrences of x in A"*

This is my working solution:

```
public int countOccurrencesOfX_Recursive(int[] array, int x, int index, int occurrences) {
    if (index == array.length) {
        return occurrences;
    }
    if (array[index] == x) {
        return countOccurrencesOfX_Recursive(array, x, index+1, occurrences+1);
    } else {
        return countOccurrencesOfX_Recursive(array, x, index+1, occurrences);
    }
}
```

I couldn't think of another way to do it without introducing more function args. It doesn't seem great because it depends on the occurrences argument being set to 0, but a user could enter any integer they liked. My question is, is this considered a good way of keeping a counter when using recursion and if not, then how would you do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The normal solution to this is to have a non-recursive *public* function which your users call, which in turn calls a *private* function which is recursive.

For example:

```java
public static int recursiveCount(int[] array, int value) {
    return recursiveCountInternal(array, value, 0, 0);
}

private static int recursiveCountInternal(int[] array, int value, int index, int count) {
    if (index == array.length) {
        return count;
    }
    if (array[index] == value) {
        count++;
    }
    return recursiveCountInternal(array, value, index + 1, count);
}
```

Comment: That's great, just changed my solution to the exact same thing you've just posted :) that's great advice cheers man

Comment: Actually it is possible to do it with one method without the count variable as one of the parameters.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen this style of recursion before and it looks fine.

What you can do is make an overloaded function that just calls this function with an initial `occurrences` of 0 like so:

```
public int countOccurrencesOfX_Recursive(int[] array, int x, int index) {
    return countOccurrencesOfX_Recursive(array, x, index, 0);
}
```

and make the recursive function private. This will prevent your concern about users entering any number.

Answer (score 0):

You can return 1+results from the rest of the string.

```
private static int countOccurencesofIntInarrayRec(Integer[] nums, int target){
    if (nums == null || nums.length==0) return 0;
    int addNum = nums[0]==target?1:0;
    return  countOccurencesofIntInarrayRec(Arrays.copyOfRange(nums, 1, nums.length),target) + addNum;
}
```